# How to setup a bazel workspace with `rules_js` for a monorepo with multiple packages?

Tags: bazel, pnpm-workspace, bazel-rules-js

I want to setup the [bazel](https://bazel.build/) build system to build a monorepo with multiple JavaScript packages with the new [rules_js](https://github.com/aspect-build/rules_js) rule set. The documentation of [rules_js](https://github.com/aspect-build/rules_js) says that it supports "nested npm packages in a monorepo" via "workspaces", but I don't understand how to wire everything up so that:

- each package in the monorepo can have different external dependencies
- packages in the monorepo can also depend on each other

I tried using `@npm//$DEPENDENCY` in the `deps` of rules like `js_library` to refer to my npm dependencies (like with the older [rules_nodejs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs) ruleset), but I just get errors about non-existing targets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### TL;DR

Set up a pnpm workspace and use `npm_link_all_packages` multiple times to set up separate `node_modules` folders in your bin tree. Then refer to the dependencies in these `node_modules` folders by `:node_modules/$DEPENDENCY` in your `deps`.

### How does rules_js create node_modules folders?

[rules_js](https://github.com/aspect-build/rules_js) uses the `npm_link_all_packages` rule to set up `node_modules` folders based on a `pnpm-lock.yaml` lockfile. This is similar to the `pnpm install` command of the [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) package manager. The difference is that `pnpm install` creates the `node_modules` folders in the source tree and `npm_link_all_packages` creates them in the bin tree.

Since you want that each package can have different external dependencies, they each need to have their own `node_modules`. [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) supports a single lock file for multiple packages if you set up a [pnpm workspace](https://pnpm.io/workspaces). The resulting lock file can be used by `rules_js` to set up a Bazel workspace with multiple packages that each get their own `node_modules` folder in the bin tree. The `npm_link_all_packages` rule will automatically set up the correct `node_modules` folder based on the Bazel package name and the `pnpm-lock.yaml`.

So you have to set up a pnpm workspace and use `npm_link_all_packages` multiple times to set up separate `node_modules` folders in your bin tree.

### How exactly do I set this up?

To achieve this, you can put the following pieces in your workspace root:

- `pnpm-workspace.yaml` to configure the list of [pnpm workspace](https://pnpm.io/workspaces) packages
- `pnpm-lock.yaml` to record how all all direct and indirect npm dependencies are resolved
- `WORKSPACE.bazel` to setup `rules_js`
- `package.json` to avoid confusing `pnpm`, and in case you want global scripts or settings for your IDE or similar
- `BUILD.bazel` to create the virtual store with `npm_link_all_packages`

And in each pnpm workspace package `$PACKAGE` you put:

- `$PACKAGE/package.json` to configure the direct npm dependencies of `$PACKAGE`
- `$PACKAGE/BUILD.bazel` to create the `node_modules folder` in the bin tree with `npm_link_all_packages`, and for your `js_library` or similar

So every pnpm workspace package is also a bazel package (since it has a `BUILD.bazel`).

### How can I refer to my npm dependencies in `deps`?

In the `deps` of `js_library` and similar, you can point to the dependencies in the `node_modules` folders generated by `npm_link_all_packages`. Typically, the `js_library` is in the same Bazel package as the `npm_link_all_package`, so you can just use `:node_modules/$DEPENDENCY`. If the `js_library` is in a sub-package of `$PACKAGE`, you can use `//$PACKAGE:node_modules/$DEPENDENCY` instead. Then in your JavaScript files, you can `import from "$DEPENDENCY"` or `require("$DEPENDENCY")`. This will work out at runtime because the `node_modules` folder will be at an appropriate place in the runfiles for `node` to find it.

### How can the packages in my workspace refer to each other?

If you want one of your packages `$PACKAGE` to depend on another one of your packages `$OTHER`, you put a `"$OTHER": "workspace:*"` into the `$PACKAGE/package.json` as usual with [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/). You also have to make sure that the default target of `$OTHER` (for example, `//some/path/to/other:other`) is an `npm_package` rule. Then you can use `:node_modules/$OTHER` or `//$PACKAGE:node_modules/$OTHER` in the deps of a `js_library` or similar to refer to `$OTHER` just like you would refer to an npm dependency.

### How can I create the `pnpm-lock.yaml`?

Note that this is a working [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) setup with some additional `BUILD.bazel` files, so you can:

- use `pnpm install --lockfile-only` to create the `pnpm-lock.yaml`
- use `pnpm install` to create the `pnpm-lock.yaml` and also create `node_modules` folders in the source tree. These folders are not needed for `rules_js` but can be helpful for your IDE.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for sharing the answer. But I was wondering if you can put a bare bones code structure in github? I am newbie to Bazel and would appreciate if I can see a skeleton of the code structure.

Comment: Hello @toxaris just checking if you had a demo repo for this?

Comment: @Chantz: In the meantime, I learned that Aspect provides an example there: https://github.com/aspect-build/bazel-examples/tree/main/pnpm-workspaces

Comment: Sorry i am late here, is pnpm mandate here to migrate from rules_nodejs to rules_js?